# Morita equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ and $S$ be two rings and $T=R\times S$. Is it true that $R$ and $T$ are Morita equivalent?

Note: We know that  two rings $R$ and $S$ are Morita equivalent if and only
$S\cong e{M}_{{n}}(R)e$ (isomorphism of rings) for some positive integer $n$ and idempotent $e$ in the matrix ring $M_n(R)$.

Comment: The statement in your Note is not true. If $R$ and $S$ are Morita equivalent then there is such an idempotent $e$, but for the converse you also need $M_n(R)eM_n(R)=M_n(R)$ ($e$ is a "full idempotent"). I'm guessing you wanted to take the idempotent $e=(1,0)\in R\times S$, so that $R\cong e(R\times S)e$, but this is not a full idempotent, since $(R\times S)e(R\times S)=R\times0\neq R\times S$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard. Many thanks for your useful comments.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. For instance if $R$ is simple, then any ring Morita-equivalent to it is also simple, but $R\times S$ is never simple if $S$ is non-zero.